# lock google sheet cell once data is entered

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a script that will allow for a cell to be locked once data has been entered.

For instance I have a sign in sheet that has several columns.
ColumnA= Student Name, ColumnB= check box for checking in, ColumnC= check box for checking out, ColumnD= Time, ColumnE= Dropdown list for reasons.

My desire is that once data is entered the cells are locked so that once StudentA inserts their information then StudentB that access the google sheet at a later time can not purposefully or accidentally adjust StudentA's info.

Is this a possibility with a script, I know that I cannot do it with conditional formatting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's cleanest to do it with a form. Do the students need to be able to see each others signins or their own in retrospect?